# Docker containers on the same network cannot access each other's exposed ports (Linux)

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-network, docker-stack

Here's a fairly simple docker stack that I've deployed:

```
version: "3"
services:
  mysql:
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=welcome
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=db1
      - MYSQL_USER=dbuser
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=welcome
      - MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=*
      - MYSQL_LOG_CONSOLE=true
    image: mysql/mysql-server:latest
    deploy:
    replicas: 1
    restart_policy:
     condition: on-failure
    ports:
     - "3306:3306"
   networks:
    - test_net
repository:
  environment:
    - DB_USER=dbuser
    - DB_PASSWORD=welcome
    - DB_HOST=mysql
    - DB_PORT=3306
  image: private_repo/repository-service:0.1.3
  deploy:
    replicas: 1
    restart_policy:
      condition: on-failure
  ports:
    - "9091:80"
  networks:
    - test_net
deployment:
  environment:
      - DB_USER=dbuser
      - DB_PASSWORD=welcome
      - DB_HOST=mysql
      - DB_PORT=3306
  image: private_repo/deployment-service:0.1.3
  deploy:
    replicas: 1
    restart_policy:
      condition: on-failure
  ports:
    - "9092:80"
  networks:
    - test_net
networks:
  test_net:
```

After docker stack deploy I can see all services running. However, when I try to access the REST API of either the repository or deployment service from a program on the **host** system such as Postman, this does not work (connection just hangs). So I did some debugging:

1) The containers can ping each other on the overlay network using the service names. For example

```
docker exec -i edb7432cdb64 ping mysql
PING mysql (10.0.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2 (10.0.0.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.050 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2 (10.0.0.2): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.065 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2 (10.0.0.2): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.058 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2 (10.0.0.2): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.083 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2 (10.0.0.2): icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.062 ms
```

2) From one container I can use curl to access another container but only on the **internal** port.

For example this works:

```
docker exec -i edb7432cdb64 curl http://models:80/services/v1/models
```

But this returns an error:

```
docker exec -i edb7432cdb64 curl http://models:9091/services/v1/models

curl: (7) Failed connect to models:9091; Connection refused
```

3) The overlay network seems to be missing information:

```
docker inspect tf0z2ht7tfhe
[
  {
    "Name": "repository2_test_net",
    "Id": "tf0z2ht7tfhefrcqvh4g0a2zq",
    "Created": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "Scope": "swarm",
    "Driver": "overlay",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "",
        "Options": null,
        "Config": null
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Attachable": false,
    "Ingress": false,
    "ConfigFrom": {
        "Network": ""
    },
    "ConfigOnly": false,
    "Containers": null,
    "Options": {
        "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "4097"
    },
    "Labels": {
        "com.docker.stack.namespace": "repository2"
    }
  }
]
```

When I try deploying this exact stack on my Mac it works! And the same inspect of the overlay network is far more informational. For one thing it shows a list of containers and also gives me a subnet and gateway.

Somehow on my Linux machine the networking for the overlay is not setup quite right. I'm not sure what configuration I might have missed though. There does not appear to be much difference between docker stack/swarm for Mac and docker stack/swarm for Linux. Any pointers as to what to look at or try next would be very much appreciated.

```
docker -v 
Docker version 17.06.2-ol, build d02b7ab
```

Comment: The contents of `docker-compose.yml` you provided seems to have wrong indentation. I assume your actual file is correct?

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that although I cannot access services using localhost:9091 for example, I can access them using the swarm manager address.

```
swarm init
Swarm initialized: current node (a5aiio3xh1qfpnw6gf8keam4y) is now a manager.

To add a worker to this swarm, run the following command:

docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-2e1yxt76ui6syrk2p4970hns25n57tquvprxn1l160vnrk0bog-bi10m0b0jcz54cv17pd469a26 10.*.*.*:2377

To add a manager to this swarm, run 'docker swarm join-token manager' and follow the instructions.
```

I can access my service at 10.*.*.*:9091. Not sure why this only happens on Linux or whether there's a way to use localhost in this configuration. But for now this works.

Answer (score -1):

The port mapping **only affects the host** (or in your case, I suppose, the swarm manager). Within the user-defined network, containers only see each other's **actual ports**. If you want to access some container via port you mapped to your host, you need to use host's IP: `docker exec -i edb7432cdb64 curl http://<Swarm manager IP>:9091/services/v1/models`. But this would be rather awkward and fairly useless.

Comment: All I want to do is access the containers from an external source (ex. a browser). I was under the impression that the host would be my host machine, but that's not what I'm seeing. It looks as if the ports are being mapped to the swarm manager and external apps have to use the swarm manager IP and the exposed ports. Is that normal?

Comment: @SimeonG, actually it's not. All exposed ports should be accessible from any swarm node. And the fact that `docker inspect` shows no containers in your overlay network is an indication that something is wrong, but I don't know what :)